# APEX 4.2 Submit form and redirect to same page

Tags: forms, branch, apex

So here's an issue with APEX 4.2. I've created an application with some forms and reports.

So I have page 2 which has a Form and a Report beneath that, I made a trigger that, when data is inserted in the table cohesive with the form, automatically fills up a table which is at its turn cohesive with the report (also on page 2).

On this page there is also 4 buttons (Create, Save, Delete and Cancel) now my goal is to submit the data from the form and redirect me back to the same page with all the values in place. I've added a Branching which should fill up my primary key but according to the debugging no data is passed back at the page after the submit (it is saved in the database however) after navigating back and forth to the page the data can be viewed normally.

I'm blundering in the dark here and I can't seem to get it working as I want it to, any help with this would be very appreciated. ^^

Thanks in advance!

Greets J.I.N.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, I used a process to recreate the primary key (which was originally created from several other columns in the database) and passed that to the page item that should contain the data.